# How to fix 'The name 'k' does not exist in the current context' error?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, for-loop, nested-loops

I only get the System.IndexOutOfRangeException error when running the solution normally but is all okay when stepping into through the whole loop.

[image: a busy cat]

I have tried the to catch the exception but no joy.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < jobs.Length; j++)
            {
                if (jobs[j].JobID == false)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < threads.Length; k++)
                    {
                        if (threads[k] != null)
                        {
                            if (!(threads[k].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped) | !(threads[k].ThreadState == ThreadState.Unstarted))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            threads[k] = new Thread(() => CountUp("ftp://ftp.net" + jobs[j].FTPFolder, HomePath + jobs[j].localFolder, j));
                            threads[k].Name = "Thread " + j + "¦ ID: " + threads[k].ManagedThreadId.ToString();
                            jobs[j].JobID = true;
                            //threads[k].Start();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(exception);
                            throw;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            StartThreads();
        }
```

I expect all threads in the threads[] array to be initialised if jobs[].JobID is false.

Below is the CountUp() method:

```
        private void CountUp(string ftppath,string localFile, int jobsID)
        {
            //string conf="";
            NumberThreads++;
            //string ftpPath = "ftp://ftp.Rxsystems.net" + conf.Split('¦')[1];
            //string downloadPath = HomePath + conf.Split('¦')[0] + "\\";

            string ftpPath = ftppath;
            string downloadPath = localFile;

            List<string> MSI = new List<string>(KD.FTP.Class.ListFiles(ftpPath,
                FTPuser, FTPpass));

            if (MSI.Count > 0)
            {
                KD.File.Class.Logger(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + MSI.Count + " Files in " + ftpPath, CurDir + "\\log.txt");

                this.textBox1.AppendText(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + MSI.Count + " Files in " + ftpPath);
                //this.textBox1.AppendText("\n\r");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string ftpFile in MSI)
                {
                    KD.FTP.Class.Download(ftpPath + ftpFile,downloadPath + "\\" + ftpFile, FTPuser,FTPpass);
                    count++;
                    KD.File.Class.Logger(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + "Downloaded " + count + "/" + MSI.Count + " Files - " + ftpFile, CurDir + "\\log.txt");
                    this.textBox1.AppendText(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ", " + "Downloaded " + count + "/" + MSI.Count + " Files - " + ftpFile);
                    //this.textBox1.AppendText("\n\r");
                }
            }


            NumberThreads--;
            jobs[jobsID].JobID = false;
        }
```

The below initialises threads[] and jobs[]:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            if (File.Exists(CurDir + "\\FTPpaths.config"))
            {
                foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(CurDir + "\\FTPpaths.config"))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                    {
                        ConfigPaths.Add(line.Split('¦')[0] + "¦" + line.Split('¦')[1]);
                    }
                }

                if (ConfigPaths.Count > 0)
                {
                    jobs = new Jobs[ConfigPaths.Count];

                    for (int j = 0; j < ConfigPaths.Count; j++)
                    {
                        jobs[j] = new Jobs();
                        jobs[j].FTPFolder = ConfigPaths[j].Split('¦')[1];
                        jobs[j].localFolder = ConfigPaths[j].Split('¦')[0];
                        jobs[j].JobID = false;
                    }

                    threads = new Thread[jobs.Length];

                }


                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: "The name 'k' does not exist in the current context" is a completely different error than a System.IndexOutOfRangeException. The former is a compile error and the latter is a run-time error. Which error are you actually asking about?

Comment: The run-time error. Sorry, I thought the errors were related.

Comment: So the real problem is the OutOfRangeException? It seems like you try to take a value from the array that has an higher index as the length of the array.

Comment: What does your `CountUp()` method look like? Does it change the length of the `jobs` array perhaps?

Comment: CountUp() only does the below that is related to jobs:
jobs[jobsID].JobID = false;

Comment: You didn't present a code which initializes `threads` and `jobs` variables.

Comment: I have just updated the OP with the method that initialises `threads` and `jobs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the problem is with `j` variable which is captured from closure into delegate passed to `new Thread`. It's well know problem when actual delegate execution references the variable in state after the loop execution so it's supposed to effectively contain `jobs.Length` value which is out of range. To fix you need to introduce a local variable inside the loop to copy `j` value in, and then use this variable instead of `j` as index of `jobs` inside the delegate passed to the `Thread` constructor:

```
try
{
    var jobIdx = j;
    threads[k] = new Thread(() => CountUp("ftp://ftp.net" + jobs[jobIdx].FTPFolder, HomePath + jobs[jobIdx].localFolder, jobIdx));
    ...
    // other stuff

}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this seems to have solved the issue. I'll keep this in mind in the future.